# Creating a Bigquery table by Python API

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I'm trying to create a Bigquery table using Python API.

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

bigquery_client = bigquery.Client(project="myproject")
dataset = bigquery_client.dataset("mydataset")

table = dataset.table("mytable")
table.create()
```

I keep getting this error

> AttributeError: 'TableReference' object has no attribute 'create'

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're getting back a `TableReference` object, not a `Table` on your 2nd last line (`table = dataset.table("mytable")`). You need to do this:

```
[..]
table_ref = dataset.table('my_table')
table = bigquery.Table(table_ref, schema=SCHEMA)
table = client.create_table(table)
[..]
```

See [here](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigquery/usage.html).

Answer (score 7):

Similar answer, with an example of `schema` and another [source](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schemas#python)

```py
from google.cloud import bigquery

# Construct a BigQuery client object.
client = bigquery.Client()

# TODO(developer): Set table_id to the ID of the table to create.
# table_id = "your-project.your_dataset.your_table_name"

schema = [
    bigquery.SchemaField("full_name", "STRING", mode="REQUIRED"),
    bigquery.SchemaField("age", "INTEGER", mode="REQUIRED"),
]

table = bigquery.Table(table_id, schema=schema)
table = client.create_table(table)  # Make an API request.
print(
    "Created table {}.{}.{}".format(table.project, table.dataset_id, table.table_id)
)
```